# How to pass HttpPost( URI ) with Volley Request ?

Tags: android, android-volley

How to pass HttpPost( URI ) with StringRequest using Volley ? I need to pass URI, with Request, like ,

```
HttpPost localHttpPost = new HttpPost(" some URI ");
```

How to do using Volley request ?

Comment: have a look this https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you need a requestQueue.

```
 requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

Then, having this requestQueue defined in some place on your code (A global variable) the work is defining a Request. It could be for example a StringRequest. Notice the Method.POST in the code.

```
 StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Method.POST, getBaseUrl() + POST_OPPORTUNITIES_URL, requestListener, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            //Manage the error
        }
    });
```

And finally add the request to de Queue

```
    requestQueue.add(req);
```